# How do i pass String from Php to VO file to another .as file in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hi I am pretty new to AS3, i am trying to parse some data from php to a VO file, and then transfer the string of data into another .as file where it will put the data into boxes. I am stuck in how do i parse the data from the VO file into the other .as File(Pulling the data from php into BookVO, then parsing BookVO to VectorTest). I tried tracing the data in BookVO, it works ok, but i can't get the data from BookVO to VectorTest.

Please help, thanks

BookVO.as

```
package  com.clark
{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;


    public class BookVO 
    {
        public var nobed1:String;
        public var LoZip1:String;
        public var rangelow1:String;
        public var rangehigh1:String;
        public var Bend:URLRequest;
        public var variabless:URLVariables;
        public var nLoader:URLLoader;


        public function BookVO() {


            Bend = new URLRequest("http://localhost/Autoresult.php");
            Bend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;



            variabless = new URLVariables();
            Bend.data = variabless;


            nLoader = new URLLoader();
            nLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            nLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Jandler);
            nLoader.load(Bend);


            // handler for the PHP script completion and return of status
             function Jandler(event:Event) {
                 var responseVariables: URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data); 
        this.nobed1 = responseVariables.nobed1 ;
        this.LoZip1 = responseVariables.LoZip1;
         this.rangelow1 = responseVariables.rangelow1;
        this.rangehigh1 = responseVariables.rangehigh1;
    }           
            }       
    }
}
```

VectorTest.as

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class VectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function VectorTest() 
        {
            super();


            var books:Vector.<BookVO> = new Vector.<BookVO>();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {

                var book:BookVO = new BookVO();
                book.nobed1 = "nobed1";
                book.LoZip1 ="LoZip1";
                book.rangelow1 = "rangelow1";
                book.rangehigh1 ="rangehigh1";
                books.push(book);

            }


            for (var j:int = 0; j < books.length; j++) 
            {
                trace("Test", j, "has a name of", books[j].nobed1);
                trace("Test", j, "Zip", books[j].LoZip1);
                trace("Test", j, "ranglow", books[j].rangelow1);
                trace("Test", j, "rangehigh", books[j].rangehigh1);
                books[j].nobed1;
                books[j].LoZip1;
                books[j].rangelow1;
                books[j].rangehigh1;
            }


            var currentY:int = 270;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < books.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing2 = new Listing2();
                Bolder.x=80;

                var tf:TextField = new TextField();
                var tf1:TextField = new TextField();
                tf1.width = 100;
                var tf2:TextField = new TextField();
                tf2.width = 100;
                tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                tf.width = 100;
                tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf1.width = 100;
                tf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf2.width = 100;
                tf1.y= tf.height+5;


                    // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO
                tf2.text = books[k].nobed1;
                tf1.text = books[k].rangelow1;
                tf.text = books[k].rangehigh1;
                tf1.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.5
                tf2.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.5


                tf.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.5
                tf.y = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.15
                Bolder.addChild(tf);
                Bolder.addChild(tf1);
                Bolder.addChild(tf2);

                    // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentY;


                addChild(Bolder);
                currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, good job on your classes.  Much better than most people who say they're new to AS3.  ;)

That said...

- In `VectorTest`, you're calling `super()` on a MovieClip.  You don't need this.
- If you're not using the timeline of a MovieClip (which, I'd recommend not using anyway), extend `Sprite` instead; it's lightweight as it doesn't carry the timeline baggage MovieClip does.
- Your first `for loop` in VectorTest Constructor loops to `length`... of no array.
- You're overwriting the properties of `BookVO` in that loop, which should be populated by your `URLLoader`.  This is superfluous.
- Your second loop references the 4 properties of `BookVO`, neither reporting or setting the variables (ie., `books[j].nobed1;`).  Might want to remove that.
- In `BookVO`, you've written a nested function.  Unless you're dealing with a massive number of variables and have issues with variable scope, don't do it.  As it stands, the only variables `Jandler()` is accessing are already Class level globals.

Loading data is an asynchronous operation, meaning, data doesn't populate instantly (LoadRequest > Wait > ProgressEvent > Wait > LoadComplete).  Because you're both instantiating `BookVO` and reading the properties in the same function, all you'll get are null properties.  Unlike the `VectorTest` constructor, because `Jandler()` is called on `Event.COMPLETE` (asynchronously), it will have access to the variables you're looking for.

---

### Try this instead...

You'll still need to address the `length` of how many books you want to instantiate, however, I've split out your reading of the properties from the constructor, and added a reference to the method to call when the loading is complete.

It will print out all the variables, and if it is the last book in your Vector, it'll call `finish()` which... um... does the rest of what you were doing.  :)

-Cheers

**BookVO** *Updated 2013.11.07 @ 12:30 AM*

```
package  com.clark{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class BookVO {
        public var nobed1:String;
        public var LoZip1:String;
        public var rangelow1:String;
        public var rangehigh1:String;
        public var Bend:URLRequest;
        public var variabless:URLVariables;
        public var nLoader:URLLoader;
        private var callMethod:Function;
        public var data:Object;

        public function BookVO(listener:Function = null) {
            Bend = new URLRequest("http://localhost/Autoresult.php");
            Bend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            variabless = new URLVariables();
            Bend.data = variabless;

            nLoader = new URLLoader();
            nLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            nLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Jandler);
            nLoader.load(Bend);

            if (listener != null) {
                callMethod = listener;
            }
        }

        public function Jandler(event:Event) {
            // handler for the PHP script completion and return of status
            var responseVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
            data = event.target.data;
            report(data);

            if (callMethod != null) {
                callMethod(this);
            }
        }

        private function report(obj:*, prefix:String = ""):void {
            for (var k in obj) {
                var type:String = getType(obj[k]);
                if (type == "Array" || type == "Object" || type == "Vector") {
                    trace(prefix + k + ": (" + type + ") ¬")
                    report(obj[k], prefix + "  ")
                } else {
                    trace(prefix + k + ":" + obj[k] + " (" + type + ")")
                }
            }
        }

        private function getType(value:*):String {
            // Returns the class name of object passed to it.
            var msg:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(value);
            if (msg.lastIndexOf("::") != -1) {msg = msg.split("::")[1];}
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

**VectorTest**

```
package  com.clark {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class VectorTest extends MovieClip {
        public var books:Vector.<BookVO>;
        public function VectorTest() {
            books = new Vector.<BookVO>();
            for (var i:int = 0; i < length; i++)  {
                var book:BookVO = new BookVO(response);
                books.push(book);
            }
        }

        private function response(book:BookVO):void {
            trace("Name: ", book.nobed1);
            trace("Zip: ", book.LoZip1);
            trace("ranglow: ", book.rangelow1);
            trace("rangehigh: ", book.rangehigh1);

            // call finish() if this is the last book.
            if (books.indexOf(book) == books.length - 1) {
                finish();
            }
        }

        private function finish():void {
            var currentY:int = 270;
            for (var k:int = 0; k < books.length; k++) {
                var Bolder:Listing2 = new Listing2();
                Bolder.x=80;

                var tf:TextField = new TextField();
                var tf1:TextField = new TextField();
                tf1.width = 100;
                var tf2:TextField = new TextField();
                tf2.width = 100;
                tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                tf.width = 100;
                tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf1.width = 100;
                tf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                tf2.width = 100;
                tf1.y = tf.height+5;

                // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO
                tf2.text = books[k].nobed1;
                tf1.text = books[k].rangelow1;
                tf.text = books[k].rangehigh1;
                tf1.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.5
                tf2.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.5


                tf.x = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.5
                tf.y = (Bolder.height-tf.height)*.15
                Bolder.addChild(tf);
                Bolder.addChild(tf1);
                Bolder.addChild(tf2);

                // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentY;

                addChild(Bolder);
                currentY += Bolder.height + 35;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer!! I will give it a try now, and haha i am pretty new to AS3, just started for a month or 2. Trying to get good at OOP, then moving onto MVC framework etc, so many more obstacles are going to come haha

Comment: Just 1 question, for the Length part(in Vecttest line20), books = new Vector.<BookVO>(); for (var i:int = 0; i < 2; i++) How would i code it to make it automatically stop after the last data?(At the moment i am testing it with extra set of if (books.indexOf(book) == books.length - 1) {finish(); Because the length varies in different users. I put books.length, and it doesnt load anything. If i set an exact value, it loops itself. I also got null for name, but i think, it might be somewhere i have a typo,cos i trace data, every part returned fine. Thanks man!!

Comment: been...6 hours, i dont seem to be able to find out why the "Name:" is returning Null,Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null. But the rest of the variables are all returning the responseVariables fine.

Comment: **1:** You need to determine the number of `book` objects you expect to receive from `Autoresult.php`.  The way you've written it, it will only ever pull off one set of variables in your `Jandler()` function.  Without knowing what's inside `responseVariables`, I can only imagine you need to save that object to the class, rather than the individual sub-properties.
**2:** This comes back to what you're actually receiving from `responseVariables`.  Try this: `for (var k in responseVariables) { trace(k + ":" + responseVariables[k]); }`.  If you have nested objects, you'd need to iterate those too.

Comment: Ahh ok, yer i will look into the book objects when i fix the null issue, but from Autoresult.php, which i am just testing, all I did was just put some text inside the fields. It seems so odd that it pulled the responseVariables ok for the 2nd,3rd and 4th field, also trace "event.target.data" with no problem(but not the first variable). Another odd thing is the boxes arent generated, all the variables are in the output window. I will spend more time to dig deeper tomorrow, didn't have much time today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am trying to understand the null issue, so i can learn As3 thoroughly. So i deleted the tf Textfield so that name won't parse through(as it was causing the problem), and it created the boxes, so i guess if i can resolve the null issue, and determine how many variables will come through then i am done for this part!

Comment: The boxes you're generating in `VectorTest` are being created on `VectorTest`, not the `stage`. When you call `addChild()` the method is being called on the current namespace (in this case, your class).  This means `this` refers to `VectorTest`, whereas `this` refers to the stage when writing document code.  If you want to add it to the stage, either add `VectorTest` to the stage, or change your `addChild()` to `stage.addChild()`.  That, however, will only work if `VectorTest` has a reference to the stage, either by being parented, or by passing the variable through the constructor.

Comment: I managed to get that part, thinking on the length part, i assume when i parse the data from php into VectorTest, i can use trace(books.length); to determine the length of the string? Then pass that info "length" onto the next set of function? so AS3 knows how many objects it is looking at? Just wondering if my logic is correct? So then i can give it a go

Comment: `books` is a Vector datatype, not a string.  `length` on a string is a property that defines the number of characters in that string, whereas in an Array/Vector, it defines the number of indices.  Since these are implicit properties of the object, you don't need to pass that info around as long as you have a reference to the object.  I'd suggest hopping on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29004/adobe-scripting-languages if you want to discuss this further, and if any of this was helpful, please don't forget to rate/accept.  ;)

Comment: Thanks i just accepted the answer, i cant rate yet or go to that room, apparently because i dont have enough reputation points lol

Comment: Ah, sorry about the chat (I forgot about the rep requirement).  In any case, this is going to come down to what you're expecting to receive from your `Autoresult.php`.  This is all part of debugging (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762607/1119-access-of-possibly-undefined-property-monster-through-a-reference-with-sta/19770876#19770876).  I've also updated the BookVO class (above) to trace all of the data you might be getting (x-ray vision for variables).  If it's in there, you shouldn't have to guess.  Just test, and pull the variables that you know are there.

Comment: Thanks, i will give that a go, i was looking at it, and realised that it is only the first variable that comes in is null, even if i change the position around, always the first variable is null, all the rest are fine.

Comment: Just tried it, now all the fields are null, i will try the debugger now. Thanks again!Sorry its taking so much of your time!

Comment: Those fields are null because I removed the setting of those individual variables in handler (you can add them back). Instead, take a look at the fact that the data that you were saving is being put into a public property called data. From the outside, you should be able to access any variable.

Comment: The odd thing is i added them back but then the first variable and the third variable turned Null, the other 2 is ok. I will check whats going wrong.

Comment: The output said the error is at VectTest line 53 
tf2.text = books[k].nobed1; from line 27 if (books.indexOf(book) == books.length - 1) { finish();   something happens when the data is passed through this point. That caused the null?